# how to resolve undeclared inclusion(s) in rule while doing cross-compilation using Bazel

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to understand Bazel and do cross-compilation for a simple c++ file

Here is my example:

```
├── aarch64_compiler
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── cc_toolchain_config.bzl
│   └── CROSSTOOL
├── aarch64_compiler.BUILD
├── helloworld
│   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   └── src
│       └── helloworld.cpp
└── WORKSPACE
```

and here is each file,

**WORKSPACE**

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "aarch64_compiler",
    path = "/",
    build_file = "aarch64_compiler.BUILD",
)
```

**aarch64_compiler.BUILD**

```
package(default_visibility = ['//visibility:public'])

filegroup(
  name = 'gcc',
  srcs = [
    'usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc',
  ],
)

filegroup(
  name = 'ar',
  srcs = [
    'usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ar',
  ],
)

filegroup(
  name = 'ld',
  srcs = [
    'usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld',
  ],
)

filegroup(
  name = 'nm',
  srcs = [
    'usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-nm',
  ],
)

filegroup(
  name = 'objcopy',
  srcs = [
    'usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-objcopy',
  ],
)

filegroup(
  name = 'objdump',
  srcs = [
    'usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump',
  ],
)

filegroup(
  name = 'strip',
  srcs = [
    'usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-strip',
  ],
)

filegroup(
  name = 'as',
  srcs = [
    'usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-as',
  ],
)

filegroup(
  name = 'compiler_pieces',
  srcs = glob([
    'usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/**',
    'usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/**',
  ]),
)

filegroup(
  name = 'compiler_components',
  srcs = [
    ':gcc',
    ':ar',
    ':ld',
    ':nm',
    ':objcopy',
    ':objdump',
    ':strip',
    ':as',
  ],
)
```

**aarch64_compiler/BUILD**

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load(":cc_toolchain_config.bzl", "cc_toolchain_config")

cc_toolchain_suite(
  name = 'toolchain',
  toolchains = {
  'aarch64|compiler':':gcc-linux-aarch64',
  "aarch64": ":gcc-linux-aarch64",
  },
)

filegroup(
    name = "empty",
    srcs = [],
)

filegroup(
    name = "arm_linux_all_files",
    srcs = [
    "@aarch64_compiler//:compiler_pieces",
    ],
)

cc_toolchain_config(name = "aarch64_toolchain_config")

cc_toolchain(
  name = 'gcc-linux-aarch64',
  toolchain_identifier = "aarch64-linux-gnu",
  toolchain_config = ":aarch64_toolchain_config",
  all_files = ':arm_linux_all_files',
  compiler_files = ':arm_linux_all_files',
  #cpu = 'aarch64',
  dwp_files = ':empty',
  #dynamic_runtime_libs = [':empty'],
  linker_files = ':arm_linux_all_files',
  objcopy_files = ':arm_linux_all_files',
  #static_runtime_libs = [':empty'],
  strip_files = ':arm_linux_all_files',
  supports_param_files = 1,
)
```

**aarch64_compiler/cc_toolchain_config.bzl**

```
# toolchain/cc_toolchain_config.bzl:
load("@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:cc_toolchain_config_lib.bzl", "tool_path")

def _impl(ctx):
    tool_paths = [
        tool_path(
            name = "gcc",
            path = "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "ld",
            path = "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "ar",
            path = "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ar",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "cpp",
            path = "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-cpp",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "gcov",
            path = "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcov",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "nm",
            path = "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-nm",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "objdump",
            path = "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump",
        ),
        tool_path(
            name = "strip",
            path = "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-strip",
        ),
    ]
    return cc_common.create_cc_toolchain_config_info(
        ctx = ctx,
        toolchain_identifier = "aarch64-linux-gnu",
        host_system_name = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu",
        target_system_name = "aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu",
        target_cpu = "aarch64",
        target_libc = "unknown",
        compiler = "aarch64",
        abi_version = "unknown",
        abi_libc_version = "unknown",
        tool_paths = tool_paths,
    )

cc_toolchain_config = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
    attrs = {},
    provides = [CcToolchainConfigInfo],
)
```

**aarch64_compiler/CROSSTOOL**

```
major_version: "local"
minor_version: ""
default_target_cpu: "aarch64"

default_toolchain {
  cpu: "aarch64"
  toolchain_identifier: "aarch64-linux-gnu"
}

toolchain {
  abi_version: "aarch64"
  abi_libc_version: "aarch64"
  builtin_sysroot: ""
  compiler: "compiler"
  host_system_name: "aarch64"
  needsPic: true
  supports_gold_linker: true
  supports_incremental_linker: false
  supports_fission: false
  supports_interface_shared_objects: false
  supports_normalizing_ar: false
  supports_start_end_lib: true
  target_libc: "aarch64"
  target_cpu: "aarch64"
  target_system_name: "aarch64"
  toolchain_identifier: "aarch64-linux-gnu"

  cxx_flag: "-std=c++11"
  linker_flag: "-lstdc++"
  linker_flag: "-lm"
  linker_flag: "-fuse-ld=gold"
  linker_flag: "-Wl,-no-as-needed"
  linker_flag: "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now"
  linker_flag: "-pass-exit-codes"

  cxx_builtin_include_directory: "/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/7/"
  cxx_builtin_include_directory: "/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/7/backward"
  cxx_builtin_include_directory: "/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/"
  cxx_builtin_include_directory: "/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include"
  cxx_builtin_include_directory: "/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed"

  objcopy_embed_flag: "-I"
  objcopy_embed_flag: "binary"

  unfiltered_cxx_flag: "-fno-canonical-system-headers"
  unfiltered_cxx_flag: "-Wno-builtin-macro-redefined"
  unfiltered_cxx_flag: "-D__DATE__=\"redacted\""
  unfiltered_cxx_flag: "-D__TIMESTAMP__=\"redacted\""
  unfiltered_cxx_flag: "-D__TIME__=\"redacted\""
  compiler_flag: "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE"
  compiler_flag: "-fstack-protector"
  compiler_flag: "-Wall"
  compiler_flag: "-Wunused-but-set-parameter"
  compiler_flag: "-Wno-free-nonheap-object"
  compiler_flag: "-fno-omit-frame-pointer"

  tool_path { name: "ld" path: "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld" }
  tool_path { name: "cpp" path: "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-cpp" }
  tool_path { name: "dwp" path: "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-dwp" }
  tool_path { name: "gcov" path: "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcov" }
  tool_path { name: "nm" path: "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-nm" }
  tool_path { name: "objcopy" path: "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-objcopy" }
  tool_path { name: "objdump" path: "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump" }
  tool_path { name: "strip" path: "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-strip" }
  tool_path { name: "gcc" path: "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" }
  tool_path { name: "ar" path: "/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ar" }

  compilation_mode_flags {
    mode: DBG
    # Enable debug symbols.
    compiler_flag: "-g"
  }
  compilation_mode_flags {
    mode: OPT

    # No debug symbols.
    # Maybe we should enable https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DebugFission for opt or
    # even generally? However, that can't happen here, as it requires special
    # handling in Bazel.
    compiler_flag: "-g0"

    # Conservative choice for -O
    # -O3 can increase binary size and even slow down the resulting binaries.
    # Profile first and / or use FDO if you need better performance than this.
    compiler_flag: "-O2"
    compiler_flag: "-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1"

    # Disable assertions
    compiler_flag: "-DNDEBUG"

    # Removal of unused code and data at link time (can this increase binary size in some cases?).
    compiler_flag: "-ffunction-sections"
    compiler_flag: "-fdata-sections"
    linker_flag: "-Wl,--gc-sections"
  }
  linking_mode_flags { mode: DYNAMIC }

    feature {
      name: 'coverage'
      provides: 'profile'
      flag_set {
        action: 'preprocess-assemble'
        action: 'c-compile'
        action: 'c++-compile'
        action: 'c++-header-parsing'
        action: 'c++-header-preprocessing'
        action: 'c++-module-compile'
        flag_group {
        flag: '-fprofile-arcs'
        flag: '-ftest-coverage'
        }
      }

      flag_set {
        action: 'c++-link-interface-dynamic-library'
        action: 'c++-link-dynamic-library'
        action: 'c++-link-executable'
        flag_group {
        flag: '-lgcov'
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**helloworld/BUILD.bazel**

```
cc_binary(
    name = "helloworld",
    srcs = [ "src/helloworld.cpp" ],
)
```

**helloworld/src/helloworld.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World from BAZEL" << std::endl;
}
```

The bazel command used: `bazel build //helloworld:helloworld --cpu=aarch64 --crosstool_top=//aarch64_compiler:toolchain --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain --verbose_failures`

and I got this error:

```
ERROR: /data/cross-compile/bazel_sample/helloworld/BUILD.bazel:1:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//helloworld:helloworld':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'helloworld/src/helloworld.cpp':
  '/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/stdc-predef.h'
  '/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/7/iostream'
  '/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/7/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h'
  '/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/7/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/os_defines.h'
  '/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/features.h'
  '/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/sys/cdefs.h'
  '/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/bits/wordsize.h'
  '/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/bits/long-double.h'
  '/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/gnu/stubs.h'
  .....
```

what is the missing in my configurations?

Comment: Have you tried removing the trailing slashes for `cxx_builtin_include_directory`? From a cursory glance the two with trailing slashes are prefixes for the paths that are in your error message.

Comment: @RobinNabel tried it now but same error again

Comment: @MahmoudEmam Were you able to solve this issue? I'm having the same error. Please post an answer if you have a solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that might help:

1. You need to include these search path in the compilation command with `compiler_flag`.
2. You might also need to add `-no-canonical-prefixes` in `compiler_flag`, otherwise bazel might not be able to match understand that the path used is the same as the one declared.